# Python print process in another language

Tags: python, encoding, psutil

I want to print all the running processes in my computer. One of my processes is called `哈哈.exe`.
This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        print proc.name().encode('utf-8')
```

I get the output `??.exe` for the Chinese process. Does someone know how to display the process name correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688020/how-to-print-chinese-word-in-my-code-using-python

Please refer to this, looks same to me

Comment: I get the same output even when I write proc.name().decode('utf-8')

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try doing a format like this?

```
import psutil

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['name'])
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        pass
    else:
        print pinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

[`encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) is the wrong method for this: The result of encoding is a binary value, ready to be output to file. What you are thinking of is the  [*decode*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) function, which converts a binary value (back) to a string.

If the string doesn't display properly without encoding (or decoding), then you'll need to figure out which encoding is used, convert the name to a bytestring, and then decode it from the correct type.

---

Like many languages, Python is starting to conceptualize string handling the right way:

- textual data has no (true) encoding, or byte-semantics. The interpreter uses whatever encoding it wishes, and presents the user with characters. You have to encode it to send it to file (But, there is a default encoding: UTF-8 or locale would both makes sense, and I believe Python chooses UTF-8 for this.)
- binary data has no textual representation: You have to explicitly decode it in order to treat it as text, and that forces you to think about which encoding it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Your os is Chinese and run the script in cmd window? You could `proc.name().encode('gbk')`

Comment: What is your local encoding? Where run your script?

Comment: I tried to run it in cmd and also in the Pycharm ide. My OS is in English.

Comment: Try to open pycharm -> Perferences, find `File encoding`, change IDE and Project encoding as UTF-8, then run your script.

Comment: Get file system encoding by `sys.getfilesystemencoding()`, for example `GBK` ,  `print proc.name().decode('GBK').encode('utf-8')`. OR change pycharm encoding as GBK, `print proc.name()`

Comment: Thanks for the help but I still get the same output :(