# Python3 Window 10 print Chinese in console

Tags: python-3.x, console, window

I use python 3.6.4 and , I run code below:

```
print ("你好")
print (u"你好")
```

but i get this:

[image]

However, if it run with VS code, it can print properly:
你好
你好

i google the problem, and find a lot suggestion:

1. add  `#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-`  at the beginning
2. encode and then decode
3. `chcp 65001` in console

, but no one work.

How to print chinese properly in window console ?

Comment: Did u try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688020/how-to-print-chinese-word-in-my-code-using-python.. I tried to recreate this issue in Linux/Ubuntu, both of ur command works perfectly find in Ubuntu python3.6

Comment: yes. I try that before. It print    b'\xe5\x93\x88\xe5\x93\x88' .  as python 3 default is utf-8 encoded. Yes it work fine in Ubuntu. It just suck in window console.