# How can I display non-ascii characters in Pytest parametrize ids

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

this is my test script:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('data', [0, 1], ids=['有效', '无效'])
def test_a(data):
    assert 1
```

but the name of each id is escaped both in Pycharm and Terminal:
[image]
[image]

So, how to fix this?

Comment: print a.decode('utf-8').encode('gb2312') Dont know if this is the right encode. Similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688020/how-to-print-chinese-word-in-my-code-using-python

Comment: that's not a same story

Comment: `pytest` escapes parametrized ids, this can't be reconfigured. See [issue #2482](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2482) for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of April 2019, pytest supports this via the following configuration setting in `pytest.ini` or [other configuration](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/customize.html):

```
disable_test_id_escaping_and_forfeit_all_rights_to_community_support = True
```

With that configuration, the example in the question works as designed without changes.

This setting is documented [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions).

**Note:** as the name implies, community support may be unavailable for issues caused while running in this configuration, and it may cause issues on Windows, use it with care.

The change was merged via [pull request no. 4995](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/pull/4995), and a discussion of the somewhat esoteric-née-discouraging name (and possible issues that can occur with this setting) can be found [in the linked issue (no. 2482)](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2482).